# Leader board for game on homepage

Tags: custom-field, database

I've built a simple game which is housed on my homepage. 
I'd like to create a leader board (a small results table) which displays the top three 3 scores.

How would i insert/retrieve the score data into and from my DB?

The games been coded using JS, is there wordpress php functions that would help me GET / POST this data.

thanks in advance,
Cam

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins + any of the metadata functions like http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata

Comment: @Soulseekah you may as well add that comment as an answer coz you've got it right

Answer (score 1):

Use http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins plus any of the metadata functions like http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata.